# can't click the button in appium but some others is okay

Tags: python, appium

I am just new in python and encounter a problem in writing a test case.

Actually I've tried to use find_element with xpath in Appium but it reports timeout, then I use the coordinate method and try to click the button but still fail. It is strange that some of my button can be clicked.

Below is my code:

```
    self.action2 = TouchAction(self.driver)

    i = 0
    while i < 10:
            self.driver.swipe(x / 2, y * 9/10, x / 2, y * 5/100)
            time.sleep(1)
            i += 1

    self.action2.move_to(700,2620).tap().perform()
```

I expect the cursor should move to the (x offset, y offset)but it failed.

Here is the log:

```
>       self.user_login(username, password)
>       self.action2.move_to(700,2620).tap().perform()
C:\learnPython\lib\site-packages\appium\webdriver\common\touch_action.py:115: in move_to

>       self._add_action('moveTo', self._get_opts(el, x, y))
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _

self = <appium.webdriver.common.touch_action.TouchAction object at 0x00000241EC651358>
element = 700, x = 2620, y = None, duration = None, pressure = None

>     def _get_opts(self, element, x, y, duration=None, pressure=None):
        opts = {}
        if element is not None:
>           opts['element'] = element.id
E           AttributeError: 'int' object has no attribute 'id'
```

> C:\learnPython\lib\site-packages\appium\webdriver\common\touch_action.py:160: AttributeError

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked at the source code of appium, I can see that `move_to` gets 3 parameters https://github.com/appium/python-client/blob/master/appium/webdriver/common/touch_action.py#L104

So in your case you set the `element` parameter to 700, thats why there is an error.

You can try either

```py
self.action2.move_to(x=700,y=2620).tap().perform()
```

or

```py
self.action2.move_to(None,700,2620).tap().perform()
```

Comment: It's great to resolve one problem but now it bring out another problem and it still not work:
----self._driver.execute(Command.TOUCH_ACTION, params) -------C:\learnPython\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py:321

Comment: Finally problem solved. I try to use self.action2.tap(None,700,2620).perform() instead of the above code.

Answer (score 0):

Locating elements via coordinates is not the best way to proceed, you will not be able to run the same test on devices with other screen resolution, orientation, density, etc.

So I would recommend considering alternative approaches like:

1. Make sure to use [Explicit Wait](https://experitest.com/selenium-testing/ajax_technology_selenium/) to ensure that the element is there
2. Make sure to use correct [`automationName`](http://appium.io/docs/en/writing-running-appium/caps/) capability
3. If the element is inside a [WebView](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView) - consider [switching the context to the webview](https://github.com/appium/python-client#switching-between-native-and-webview)